# MERN How to show modal or toast ONLY when user has just logged in or registered an account

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, use-effect

Someone new visits my web app and decides to sign up. When they sign up they are taken to the dashboard. Upon visiting the dashboard for the first time Id like to welcome them with a toast message or a modal.

I am using passport local and passport google oauth2.0. which always sends back a req.user object with properties.

I am not sure how to set up a useEffect to trigger this message when they visit the dashboard. Do I do something like

```
const useEffect(() => {
// show toast or modal
},[// based on cookie time? or some req.user prop?])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use LocalStorage or cookies to know if user is logged in or not then in your useEffect you can do something like this.

```
useEffect(()=>{
//don't store any user info in local storage only flag
const isLogin=localStorage.getItem("flag")//you can also use cookies
if (isLogin==true)
{
  showModal(true);
}

 },[showModal])
```

//in your return

```
return(
showModal==true?<Modal/>:<></>


)
```